# Perl How to pass filepath with spaces in folders to backticks

Tags: perl, filenames, spaces

I am trying to call svn update using backticks, with a filepath that contains spaces.

```
$folder = "D:\\Projects\\Development_SVN\\Project Hay\\Release\\Branches\\R2.3\\";
updateFolder($folder);

sub UpdateFolder {
my $SVNPath = $_[0];

    &main::logWriteAndPrint("    Updating $SVNPath (using backticks)\n");

    my $svnCmd = 'svn up --set-depth infinity '.'\''.$SVNPath.'\'';
    my $svnResp = `$svnCmd 2>&1`;

# this works
#   my $svnResp = `svn up --set-depth infinity "D:\\Projects\\Development_SVN\\Project Hay\\Release\\Branches\\R2.3" 2>&1`;
}
```

This works with no spaces:

```
my $svnCmd = 'svn up --set-depth infinity '."$SVNPath";
my $svnResp = `$svnCmd 2>&1`;
```

but with a space returns:

```
Updating 'D:\Projects\Development_SVN\Project':
At revision 20938.
Skipped 'Hay\Release\Branches\R2.3'
Summary of updates:
  Updated 'D:\Projects\Development_SVN\Project' to r20938.
Summary of conflicts:
  Skipped paths: 1
```

I've tried with double quotes, single quote, escaping the chars but just can't get it right.

I think the trailing slashes aren't helping but I've tried removing them aswell.

Thanks

Edit- Examples with command line:

C:>svn up --set-depth infinity D:\Projects\Development_SVN\Project Hay\Release\Branches\R2.3
Updating 'D:\Projects\Development_SVN\Project':
At revision 20950.
Skipped 'Hay\Release\Branches\R2.3'
Summary of updates:
Updated 'D:\Projects\Development_SVN\Project' to r20950.
Summary of conflicts:
Skipped paths: 1

C:>svn up --set-depth infinity "D:\Projects\Development_SVN\Project Hay\Release\Branches\R2.3"
Updating 'D:\Projects\Development_SVN\Project Hay\Release\Branches\R2.3':
At revision 20950.

C:>svn up --set-depth infinity "D:\Projects\Development_SVN\Project Hay\Release\Branches\R2.3\"
svn: E020024: Error resolving case of 'D:\Projects\Development_SVN\Project Hay\Release\Branches\R2.3"'

C:>svn up --set-depth infinity 'D:\Projects\Development_SVN\Project Hay\Release\Branches\R2.3'
svn: E020024: Error resolving case of ''D:\Projects\Development_SVN\Project'

C:>svn up --set-depth infinity 'D:\Projects\Development_SVN\Project Hay\Release\Branches\R2.3\'
svn: E020024: Error resolving case of ''D:\Projects\Development_SVN\Project'

Comment: I has nothing to do with the backticks.since your log shows `Updating 'D:\Projects\Development_SVN\Project':`  The folder name is already split in two when you call the function. Try [this](https://rextester.com/PJS4301) and see if it prints only half the path.

Comment: I'd use IPC::Run. Othewise, I'd use Win32::ShellQuote

Comment: @TedLyngmo Re "*your log show*", I think that's the output from `svn`, not the logged message

Comment: @ikegami I would expect `svn` to output `Skipped 'D:\Projects\Development_SVN\Project'` and `svn: E155007: None of the targets are working copies` - David is the output you show in the question from from `logWriteAndPrint` or the `svn` command?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion.  The LogWriteandPrint correctly shows:
```    
Updating D:\Projects\Development_SVN\Project Hay\Release\Branches\R2.3\ (using backticks)
```
It is the path being passed to SVN i cant get correct

Comment: How about adding `&main::logWriteAndPrint("    Backtick:command: <$svnCmd> \n");` to see what is generated? `"D:\\Projects\\Development_SVN\\Project Hay\\Release\\Branches\\R2.3\\"`is ` D:\Projects\Development_SVN\Project Hay\Release\Branches\R2.3\ ` so it might be an escaping issue.

Comment: ```&main::logWriteAndPrint("    Backtick:command: <$svnCmd> \n");```
returns```Backtick:command: <svn up --set-depth infinity D:\Projects\Development_SVN\Project Hay\Release\Branches\R2.3\>```

Comment: Trying some things on the command line $SVNPath cannot end in a back slash and has to be surrounded by double quotes.

I'm trying ```$SVNPath =~ s{(.+)/\z}{\1};``` to remove the trailing slashes but not working so far.

Comment: So this removes the trailing backslashes ```$SVNPath =~ s{(.+)\\\z}{\1};```

Comment: @DavidJanes `$SVNPath =~ s,\\+$,,;` would remove the trailing backslashes with a simpler (i.m.o.) regex. I find it very strange that `svn` prints `Updating 'D:\Projects\Development_SVN\Project':` when you have a trailing backslash but manages to print the full path when you don't. It may be an internal bug in `svn`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the guidance.  This is what I need to do:

```
my $folder = "D:\\Projects\\Development_SVN\\Project Hay\\Release\\Branches\\R2.3\\";
UpdateFolder($folder);

sub UpdateFolder {
my $SVNPath = $_[0];

    $SVNPath =~ s{(.+)\\\z}{\1};
    my $svnCmd = 'svn up --set-depth infinity';
    my $svnResp = `$svnCmd "$SVNPath" 2>&1`;

    if ($svnResp)
    {
        &main::logWriteAndPrint($svnResp);
    }
}
```

which produces output of:

```
Updating 'D:\\Projects\Development_SVN\Project Hay\Release\Branches\R2.3':
At revision 20940.
```